# What does it mean to "poison a function" in C++?

Tags: c++, constexpr

At the very end of Scott Schurr's talk ["Introducing `constexpr`" at CppCon](https://youtu.be/fZjYCQ8dzTc?t=3679), he asks "Is there a way to poison a function"? He then explains that this can be done (albeit in a non-standard way) by:

1. Putting a `throw` in a `constexpr` function
2. Declaring an unresolved `extern const char*`
3. Referencing the unresolved `extern` in the `throw`

I sense that I'm a bit out of my depth here, but I'm curious:

- What does it mean to "poison a function"?
- What is the significance/usefulness of the technique he outlines?

Comment: Never heard about that term, clarify with a concise example please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I just clarified. This a term 'widely known in small circles'

Comment: He's talking about ensuring that every call to the `constexpr` function is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @T.C. Right--he mentioned that a `constexpr` function could be used either at compile time or at run time.  So this is a way to force it so that you can't use it at run time?  When is that useful?

Comment: Especially in C++11, a `constexpr` function often isn't the most efficient implementation because of the constraints, so one may not want it evaluated at run time; or, maybe it's the error case (as in his example).

Comment: @T.C. That makes a lot of sense--thanks!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In general it refers to making a function unusable, e.g. if you want to ban the use of dynamic allocation in a program you could "poison" the `malloc` function so it can't be used.

In the video he's using it in a more specific way, which is clear if you read the slide that is displayed when he talks about poisoning the function, which says "A way to force compile-time only?"

So he is talking about "poisoning" the function to make it uncallable at run-time, so it's *only* callable in constant expressions. The technique is to have a branch in the function which is never taken when called in a compile-time context, and to make that branch contain something that will cause an error.

A `throw` expression is allowed in a constexpr function, as long as it is never reached during compile-time invocations of the function (because you can't throw an exception at compile-time, it's an inherently dynamic operation, like allocating memory). So a throw expression that refers to an undefined symbol will not be used during compile-time invocations (because that would fail to compile) and cannot be used at run-time, because the undefined symbol causes a linker error.

Because the undefined symbol is not "odr-used" in the compile-time invocations of the function, in practice the compiler will not create a reference to the symbol, so it's OK that it's undefined.

Is that useful? He's demonstrating *how* to do it, not necessarily saying it's a good idea or widely useful. If you have a need to do it for some reason then his technique might solve your problem. If you don't have a need for it, you don't need to worry about it.

One reason it *might* be useful is when the compile-time version of some operation is not as efficient as it could be. There are restrictions on the kind of expressions allowed in a constexpr function (especially in C++11, some restrictions were removed in C++14). So you might have two versions of a function for performing a calculation, one that is optimal, but uses expressions that aren't allowed in a constexpr function, and one that is a valid constexpr function, but would perform poorly if called at run-time. You could poison the sub-optimal one to ensure it is never used for run-time calls, ensuring the more efficient (non-constexpr) version is used for run-time calls.

N.B. The performance of a constexpr function used at compile-time is not really important, because it has no run-time overhead anyway. It might slow down your compilation by making the compiler do extra work, but it won't have any run-time performance cost.

Comment: I did read the text of the slide, but I didn't see the connection to the term he was using.  It's obvious now that you've explained it, but I didn't see it at the time.  Thanks very much for this excellent answer--I just love this website.

Comment: @PravasiMeet, ask your own question, don't hijack the comments of someone else's question about something different. A simple solution would be to define it as deleted in every translation unit, or replace it with your own definition that references an undefined symbol.

Answer (score 19):

'Poisoning' an identifier means that any reference to the identifier after the 'poisoning' is a hard compiler error. This technique may be used, for instance, for hard deprecation (function IS deprecated, never use it!).

In GCC traditionally there was a pragma for this: `#pragma GCC poison`.

Comment: Yes, but not quite in the sense used in that talk.

Comment: @T.C., ok, I should probably watch it before answering :)