# Is it possible to assign and verify a constexpr structure in C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I implemented a [`getop()` in C++](https://github.com/m2osw/advgetopt). This is a class with all sorts of bells and whistles.

One of those bells would be a way to verify that the user enters valid options at compile time. Already I have part of that for the flags (not shown here) but I've been trying to make it work for the `struct option` and at this time I've not had much success.

First of all, the code allows me to define an array of options using  the `define_option()` function. I want to be able to specify the fields of the option structure in any order and have some sanity checks on them. So I use a list of arguments to a template function. Each argument is a class which gets instantiated on the spot and then the `define_option()` selects the correct class for each field, extracting the value.

Up to here, everything works like a charm. Pretty basic C++.

Where I'm having a problem is inside the `define_option()` class. Say for instance that I were to try the following:

```
... define_option(...)
{
    ...
    option opt = { ... };
    static_assert(opt.f_short_name != '\0', "this failed");
    ...
}
```

Here I get an error. `static_assert()` tells me that `opt` is not constant.

> a.cpp:168:1: error: non-constant condition for static assertion

So next my step is to mark the `opt` variable a `constexpr` (something the error says to do to resolve the `static_assert()`.)

```
... define_option(...)
{
    ...
    constexpr option opt = { ... };
    ...
}
```

Now even without the `static_assert()`, the code doesn't compile. I get the following error:

> a.cpp:168:5: error: ‘args#0’ is not a constant expression

I'm thinking that it's not really doable from within the `define_option()` function, even though it's possible to check the resulting list of options as shown in the working example below. So in the end the `opt` global variable is a static fully defined at compile time (no code necessary to re-work on the table at runtime) but that doesn't help me since I can't make sure that the arguments for each option will work as expected.

I have an [online running sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/303d372ab27e4ba6) on coliru.

```
// compiled with: g++ -std=c++14 -o a ~/tmp/a.cpp
//
#include <iostream>

typedef char32_t            short_name_t;
constexpr short_name_t      NO_SHORT_NAME = L'\0';

struct option
{
    short_name_t        f_short_name = NO_SHORT_NAME;
    char const *        f_name = nullptr;
};


template<typename T, T default_value>
class OptionValue
{
public:
    typedef T   value_t;

    constexpr OptionValue<T, default_value>()
        : f_value(default_value)
    {
    }

    constexpr OptionValue<T, default_value>(T const v)
        : f_value(v)
    {
    }

    constexpr value_t get() const
    {
        return f_value;
    }

private:
    value_t     f_value;
};


class ShortName
    : public OptionValue<short_name_t, NO_SHORT_NAME>
{
public:
    constexpr ShortName()
        : OptionValue<short_name_t, NO_SHORT_NAME>()
    {
    }

    constexpr ShortName(short_name_t name)
        : OptionValue<short_name_t, NO_SHORT_NAME>(name)
    {
    }
};


class Name
    : public OptionValue<char const *, nullptr>
{
public:
    constexpr Name()
        : OptionValue<char const *, nullptr>()
    {
    }

    constexpr Name(char const * name)
        : OptionValue<char const *, nullptr>(name)
    {
    }
};


template<typename T, typename F, class ...ARGS>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, F>::value, typename T::value_t>::type find_option(F first, ARGS ...args)
{
    return first.get();
}


template<typename T, typename F, class ...ARGS>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, F>::value, typename T::value_t>::type find_option(F first, ARGS ...args)
{
    return find_option<T>(args...);
}



template<class ...ARGS>
constexpr option define_option(ARGS ...args)
{
    option opt =
    {
        .f_short_name =          find_option<ShortName   >(args..., ShortName()),
        .f_name =                find_option<Name        >(args...),
    };

    return opt;
}


constexpr option const opt[] =
{
    define_option(
        Name("--help"),
        ShortName('h')
    )
};


// this test works as expected here
// but it does not work from inside define_option()
//
static_assert(opt[0].f_name[0] != '-', "Wrong start?!");

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{

    std::cerr << "opt[0].f_short_name = " << opt[0].f_short_name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

At this time I'm limited to C++14. If there is a C++17 solution, I'd still be interested.

Comment: It sounds like C++20's `consteval` might help with your "best-case API" when it's eventually usable for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add something that makes the call non-constant. Say, throw an exception.

```
template<class ...ARGS>
constexpr option define_option(ARGS ...args)
{
    option opt =
    {
        .f_short_name =          find_option<ShortName   >(args..., ShortName()),
        .f_name =                find_option<Name        >(args...),
    };
    if(/* check fails */) throw something;

    return opt;
}
```

Then when you try to do

```
constexpr option const opt[] =
{
    define_option(
        Name("--help"),
        ShortName('h')
    )
};
```

and the check fails, the compiler will complain that this call to `define_option` is not a constant expression and cannot be used to initialize a `constexpr` variable.

You can even rig `something` to produce a linker error if this function is ever called at runtime. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964621/what-does-it-mean-to-poison-a-function-in-c).

Comment: Did you actually try that? (1) it breaks the fact that the options would be created at compile time and (2) it doesn't fail compiling... Maybe I'm doing something else wrong, but at this point that "throw" trick doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Okay, I see that coliru has g++ version 8.2.0. I'm still on 5.4.0. I guess that's why it doesn't work right  for me...